# Can't set group panel grid property

Tags: angular, wijmo, wijmo-grid

So I am using the following markup to generate a wijmo grid and associated group panel.

```
<div class="grid" >
  <wj-group-panel
    #group
    [grid]="flex"
    [placeholder]="'Drag columns here to create Groups'">
  </wj-group-panel>
  <wj-flex-grid 
    #flex
    [itemsSource]="gridData"
  >
  </wj-flex-grid>
</div>
```

I noticed that I was unable to drag anything to the group panel, and upon further digging found that the `group.grid` property was never getting set. I attempted to set it manually using `this.group.grid = this.flex`, only to find that even after doing so, console logging the `group.grid` property yielded `undefined`.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: do `npm unisnatll wijmo` `npm install devextreme devextreme/angular` ;)

Comment: @RezaRahmati if only if only...